# I will not waver

Tags: word-choice

I’m looking for another way of expressing the statement

> I will not waver.
>
> I have looked up synonyms for the word certain, but they just do not
> seem to fit into what I’m composing.

Comment: Martin Luther's translator put it this way: I cannot and will not recant anything, for to go against conscience is neither right nor safe. Here I stand, I can do no other, so help me God. Amen.https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/martin_luther_403720

Comment: The spelling of "waiver" in the title is incorrect. This has a different meaning from "waver"  used in the body of the question. [Waiver](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waiver) is a noun meaning **the act or instance of _waiving_** (or not enforcing) **a claim.**

Comment: Well, what is it you're composing?  Without that, how will we be able to suggest something that might fit better?

Answer (score 4):

You say, "I have looked up synonyms for the word certain." This means that you are looking for a *positive* expression of the phrase *I will not waiver.*

I would use:

> I will remain [**steadfast.**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steadfast)

From Merriam-Webster:

> **1 a** : firmly fixed in place : IMMOVAVABLE
>   **b** : not subject to change
>   the *steadfast* doctrine of original sin
>   —Ellen Glasgow
>   **2** : firm in belief, determination, or adherence : LOYAL
>   her followers have remained *steadfast*

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Luther's translator](http://Amen.brainyquote.com/quotes/martin_luther_403720) put it this way:

```
    I cannot and will not recant anything, for to go against conscience
 is neither right nor safe. Here I stand, I can do no other, so help me God.
```